# PHP Copy File(s) From One Server to Another (getting an error)

Tags: php

I'm trying to run this code to copy file(s) from one server to another:

```
<?php
    $from = '\\sxlsv-leapwebdv\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\leap\Deleteme.txt'; 
    $to = '\\sxlsv-leapwebqa\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\leap\Deleteme.txt'; 
    if(!@copy($from,$to)) 
    { 
        $errors= error_get_last(); 
        echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type']; 
        echo "<br />\n".$errors['message']; 
    } 
    else { 
        echo 'File copied from remote!<br />'; 
    } 
?>
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
COPY ERROR: 2
copy(/sxlsv-leapwebdv/c$/inetpub/wwwroot/leap/Deleteme.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The file DOES exist - when I navigate to that same path in Windows Explorer, I can access that directory and file.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape your backslashes. Well okay, you're using single quotes, so you're mostly good. But `'\\'` evaluates to a single backslash, to make escaping a single quote (via `'\''`) possible. So you need to change your paths to

```
$from = '\\\\sxlsv-leapwebdv\\c$\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\leap\\Deleteme.txt'; 
$to = '\\\\sxlsv-leapwebqa\\c$\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\leap\\Deleteme.txt';
```

Comment: @Sammitch Your edit is good for style, but not entirely necessary. The only possible thing where a backslash is considered an escape character is when a backslash or a single quote follows. But this is completely un-ambiguous, so thanks. :)